# How to have Android 4+ spinner look in older versions?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I don't want to use ActionBarSherlock to reduce the app size.

I found `android.support.v7.internal.widget.SpinnerICS`, but it doesn't work.

Anyone have any light to share about this?

Answer (score 1):

[HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) is what you're looking for. You must have ActionBarSherlock to use this library